# React-spring Parallax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parallax, react-spring

### Description

I'm trying to implement some parallax animation using `react-spring`, but I'm not able to find a way to space the containers in a responsive / uniform way.

### Reproducible snippet

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-parallax-forked-remdm?file=/src/App.js:394-395) I made a snippet which contains a basic parallax effect animating some divs on scroll:

```js
<Parallax pages={5}>
  <ParallaxLayer offset={0} speed={0.4} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <div className="box" />
  </ParallaxLayer>

  <ParallaxLayer offset={0.9} speed={0.6} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <div className="box" />
  </ParallaxLayer>

  <ParallaxLayer offset={1.1} speed={0.8} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <div className="box" />
  </ParallaxLayer>

  <ParallaxLayer offset={1.9} speed={1} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <div className="box" />
  </ParallaxLayer>

  <ParallaxLayer offset={2} speed={1.2} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <div className="box" />
  </ParallaxLayer>
</Parallax>
```

### Problem

Having the layers with heights based on their content make them not responsive, as each layer is specifically starting from the specified `offset` position.

### Conclusion

I would guess that works if the layers are being set with a specified viewport height, but is that really the only way?
Or am I perhaps misinterpreting the usage of this component?

Comment: Look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-parallax-forked-2k4ro - should give you a hint

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that's the snippet I shared in the question? Did you perhaps copied over the wrong link?

Comment: Hmm... The fork somehow was removed. Sorry

Comment: What do you mean by saying "have them [divs] distanced equally"?
Per documentation, The speed prop will affect the initial starting position of a layer, but not its final offset position.

Comment: Updated the question to be hopefully more understandable

Comment: Parallax effect is you want background image to be fixed and foreground text moving. Which layer you want fix and which layer should be scrollable?